# Is it possible to set/bind an ID in ngModel and show label in NGX-Bootstrap typeahead?

Tags: javascript, angular, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap Typeahead for an autocomplete.
I get an ID from the rest API and have to bind it with `ngModel`.

What I am trying to do is, bind an ID to a status(ngModel) and show the name in autocomplete.

I mean that if the status is 2 on initial load the name 'Alaska' should be selected in autocomplete.

I have tried many ways but no success yet.

Typeahed simply show the selected name as it's map with "typeaheadOptionField"

Template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="status"
       [typeahead]="statesComplex"
       typeaheadOptionField="name"
       [typeaheadMinLength]="0"
       class="form-control autocomplete-input"
       formControlName="billableStatus"
       placeholder="Select Status">
```

Component:

```
export class UserComponent  { 
    status;
    statesComplex:any[] = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Alabama'}, {id: 2, name: 'Alaska'}, {id: 3, name: 'Arizona', region: 'West'},
        {id: 4, name: 'Arkansas', {id: 5, name: 'California'},
        {id: 6, name: 'Colorado'}, {id: 7, name: 'Connecticut'},
        {id: 8, name: 'Delaware'}, {id: 9, name: 'Florida'},
        {id: 10, name: 'Georgia'}];
}
```